# Notepad++ - Ignore specific character in a search

Tags: regex, notepad++

How to find string in a file even this string includes & symbol?

For example there is a string such as "Propert&ies" in a file.

Let's assume we don't know location of  & symbol.

I mean, this string may be "P&roperties" or "Propertie&s".

How to find this string with using "Properties" word but not using & symbol?

PS: I don't want to remove & symbols in this file because these symbols are important for me.

Comment: So you're looking for `&?P&?r&?o&?p&?e&?r&?t&?i&?e&?s&?` ?

Comment: Is there any easy way? Or must I put &? to between every char manually?

Comment: Could go with `P[&ropetis]{9,10}\b` ? That would also find the anagrams. But because for that word [there don't seem to be many 10 letter anagrams](http://anagramscramble.com/anagrams-of/properties) that start with a capital P, it seems only a small risk. Or maybe not, it would also match `Poooooooo&t`

Comment: Would you be opposed to using one of the plugins in Notepad++. Like for example "Lua Script" or "Python Script"? That would give more options than using the limits of regex. And would this be only for 1 word, or an array of words?